# How to detect that the save_post hook is calling the callback associated to the current edit post page only

Tags: custom-post-types, post-meta, save-post

I am using the save_post hook to handle updates in a post that are done via the admin edit post page.

But since I have more than ten custom post types, the save_post associated to each one of them is firing when I save ANY of all the posts.

I want to add an early return to the function that will return if the save post callback does not correspond to the current editing screen.

As follows:

```
function save_post_type_WHATEVER1{
    if(not editing whatever1 cpt){
    return;
    }
}

function save_post_type_WHATEVER2{
    if(not editing whatever2 cpt){
    return;
    }
}
```

But I don't know what I could possibly check in the `if(not editing whatever2 cpt){` to achieve the desired behaviour.

I see that the URL contains a `?post=x` parameter. Would it be valid enough if I just do:

```
function save_post_type_WHATEVER2{
    if(get_post_type($_GET['post'])!='whatever2'){
    return;
    }
}
```

Or will that turn into another kind of problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any function hooked to the `save_post` hook will run whenever you save a post. That is expected behaviour.

You should use the hook `save_post_{$post->post_type}` to specify to which post type that callback is asociated. That way, it will only be called when saving a post of type `{$post->post_type}`

See the [hook documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/save_post_post-post_type/)

Comment: Wow, I never imagined this would already be a WP inbuild consideration. Amazing, thanks a lot for the information.